# Solution to simple algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't seem to be able to solve this for $x$:

$$y = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}.$$

Ans. is $$x = \ln\left(y\pm\sqrt{y^2-1}\right),$$ but I'd appreciate seeing the intermediate steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since 
$$y=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\Rightarrow (e^x)^2-2y\cdot e^x+1=0,$$
we have
$$e^x=y\pm\sqrt{y^2-1}\Rightarrow x=\ln\left(y\pm\sqrt{y^2-1}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$y=(e^x+e^−x)/2⇒(e^x+1/e^x)/2⇒\frac{((e^2x+1)/e^x)}{2}$
then
$y=\frac {(e^2x+1)}{2e^x} ⇒ 2ye^x=e^2x+1 ⇒ (ex)2−2y⋅ex+1=0$,
we have 
$e^x=(2y±((2y)^2-4))^(1/2))/2  ⇒ y±(y^2-1)^(1/2)$
finally
$ine^x= iny±(y^2-1)^{(1/2)}$
$x= iny±(y^2-1)^{(1/2)}$

Comment: If you don't learn how to properly type mathematics in this site, the probabilities that someone even read your answers is very low, not to mention upvotes.

Comment: i´m sorry, i am new!!

Comment: Thanks very much to all three who answered. At age 73 and a career in "business," I've gotten very rusty.